# How to Go asn1 marshal/unmarshal and omit fields?

Tags: go, marshalling, unmarshalling, asn.1

```
type bearer struct {
    CreatedAt time.Time     `asn1:"generalized"`
    ExpiresAt time.Time     `asn1:"generalized"`
    Nonce     string
    Signature []byte        `asn1:"-"`
    TTL       time.Duration `asn1:"-"`
    Frequency int           `asn1:"-"`
}

c := &bearer{
  CreatedAt: time.Now()
  ExpiresAt: time.Now().Add(1*time.Minute())
  Nonce: "123456789abcdefghijklmnop"
  Frequency: 1
}

b, err := asn1.Marshal(*c)
os.WriteFile("b64.txt", b, 0777)
```

Will successfully marshal the struct, however, when checking that struct with Bash `base64 -d b64.txt > b64.txt.der` I can still see that `asn1:"-"` fields were actually marshalled and written to file, and field which didn't have a value got `Error: Object has zero length.`. Why `asn1:"-"` doesnt work as it does for `json`?

Comment: If one is prepared to use commercial tools, the one from Objective Systems (obj-sys.com) supports Go. Disclosure - I am a user of these tools, not a vendor! These tools are pretty complete in their coverage of ASN.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `asn1:"-"` doesnt work as it does for `json`?

Because the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package is implemented to support the `-` option, while [`encoding/asn1`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/asn1) isn't. As to why, this is not the place. Accept that primary goal of `encoding/asn1` is to support reading and writing X.509 certificates, it doesn't mean to be a "swiss army knife" of ASN1 implementation.

If you want to exclude certain fields, create struct types that exclude those fields. To avoid repetition, you may embed these "stripped" structs in your own that includes the additional fields, e.g.:

```
type bearerAsn1 struct {
    CreatedAt time.Time `asn1:"generalized"`
    ExpiresAt time.Time `asn1:"generalized"`
    Nonce     string
}

type bearer struct {
    bearerAsn1
    Signature []byte
    TTL       time.Duration
    Frequency int
}
```

Only marshal / unmarshal `bearer.bearerAsn1`, so other fields of `bearer` will be naturally excluded.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, explicitly for pointing out that `"-"` difference in `json` and `asn1`. Accepting!